# PHP setting max CPU utilization, OR, how to forfeit CPU timeslice

Tags: php, cpu-usage

I have an application written in PHP (Not website, an application), that has an infinite loop for its logic until the application shuts down. One issue with it that I've noticed is I get incredibly high CPU usage (Obviously), and I've tried using C++ methods I've done in the past to lower the CPU usage. Not many of them seem to work.

I've tried:

```
sleep(1);
```

and:

```
time_sleep_until(microtime(true)+0.2);
```

But neither seem to lower utilization.

Any tips?

Comment: with out seeing the script, no idea.

Comment: Is this some sort of cron process?

Comment: `sleep(1);` usually does sort this problem out, although it is a horrible way to do it. A more important point is what does your application actually do? It's best to let your script stick on a blocking function call until it returns data (e.g. a socket read operation) if possible, can you show your code (or at least an outline of it)?

Comment: PoX: Nope! Not a Cron process.

Comment: DaveRandom: My script is actually an IRC bot, that's a bit overblown... haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure execution of your jobs when they are needed to be executed. So if this infinite script needs to do/check something every minute you can just do it when there is a change otherwise sleep.

Your problem can be on something else your script does other than itself. Here is an example hope it helps.

```
    set_time_limit(0);
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    $minutes = NULL;

    do {
        try {
            // Run jobs, only when the minute has changed
            $now = getdate();
            if ($now['minutes'] != $minutes) {
                $minutes = $now['minutes'];
            }       
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            // Catch here and handle
        }
        sleep(10);
    } while (TRUE);
```

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME. This works 100% great! My process went from 100% CPU to an acceptable 1.9% CPU!! :D

Comment: how is this different than a a cron job run every minute ?

Comment: I don't think people would enjoy an IRC bot connecting and disconnecting every minute...  plus it's pointless if the bot just connects and them immediately disconnects!

Comment: ok, next time explain what your doing when you ask the question.

Comment: This is like some sort of cron implementation. In my code I actually have tries and keep track of that in db. So script keeps running and will attempt again if number of tries is within certain limits and die if its more than lets say 10 attempts. I reset number of tries after every successful attempt. Glad it helped :D

Comment: My question was solved with a great answer without any further input, and I specified what I was trying to do, and what I needed. I don't think I need to go any further, my post did the job and PoX did a great job.

Comment: @RyanCopley well thanks for you lack of consideration for any one else searching S.O for a similar issue.

Comment: I know I'm 3 years late but hopefully I'll get an answer : how does this work, I run this script once (only once ? how do I interrupt it then ? or once every xxx ?) and I'm all set ?

Comment: yes you run it once and it is a never ending script you can code in ending condition in if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do this within the PHP application, but when launching the process you can pass it to a command-line utility called `cpulimit`.  Another option is to change the `nice` level of the program so at least when it is busy it won't hold up other more important processes.